# Finding $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\left(e^{1/n^2}+2e^{2^2/n^2}+\cdots+ne^{n^2/n^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg(e^{\frac{1}{n^2}}+2e^{\frac{2^2}{n^2}}+\cdots+ne^{\frac{n^2}{n^2}}\bigg)} $$

I would greatly appreciate some help with this limit.

Comment: would always be good to show what you have done on your question: probably you have heard of this already on this platform :-)

Comment: @Math-fun I am aware and I always do, but for this exercise what I tried was just embarrassing and decided to spare everyone. In other cases (and you can check my other questions) some of the things I tried actually helped but here I was certain it would only make it worse.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg(e^{\frac{1}{n^2}}+2e^{\frac{2^2}{n^2}}+...+ne^{\frac{n^2}{n^2}}\bigg)}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{1}{n}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^n \frac jn e^{\left(\frac{j}{n}\right)^2}\bigg)}\\
&=\int_0^1xe^{x^2}dx
\end{align}

Comment: Which $=(e-1)/2$.